# How to convert iframe code to object code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code for my Youtube random playlist I want to embed which works fine but the site I want to use it on won't allow iframes.

I want to convert it to an Object which is allowed on that site. I hope someone here can help me with this I don't know how to code.

Here is the URL to view the code:

```
planetpeople.x10host.com/tube.php
```